# How to save an image in a directory named on the User?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-2.2

I am using Django2.2 and I am currently learning Django. I have created a model where I have to post an image of a certain thing and that model is connected with a User. I want to save the image on a directory named on that certain user

I have a custom User Model where I created a field called Profile Photo and that profile photo is saved to a directory named on that User.But then I created another application called 'Product' and there I created many fields including an image field.I am trying to save that image on that directory named on that specific User.

```py
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
   return 'media/%s/%s' % (instance.username, filename)

 class Products(models.Model):  
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to = user_directory_path)
   product_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
         return self.title
```

When I try to save a Product and error occurs.

```py
'Products' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Is there any successful ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A `Products` instance indeed has no `username` attribute. The `product_user` has, you thus can change this to:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
   return 'media/%s/%s' % (instance.product_user.username, filename)
```

> **Note**: models have usually *singular* names, so `Product`, instead of <s>`Products`</s>.